# Make Sequelize show tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a project in node.js and one of my pages will show a list of all the tables in the database. I would like to know if Sequelize has a function like "Show tables".

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It is postgresql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's an API in Sequelize, but you can always fall back to raw SQL. "Show tables" is a MySQLism, so you could just do:

```
var seq = new Sequelize('mysql://localhost/mysql');
seq.query('show tables').then(function(rows) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
});
```

Replace the `console.log` with your own parsing and display logic.

Comment: This doesn't work for Postgre. Isn't there some common request for all (or most of) the databases?

Answer (score 11):

Use the Sequelize `showAllSchemas` method:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://localhost/mysql');

sequelize.getQueryInterface().showAllSchemas().then((tableObj) => {
    console.log('// Tables in database','==========================');
    console.log(tableObj);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log('showAllSchemas ERROR',err);
})
```

This would be the "proper" Sequelize way to do it as opposed to .query('show tables')

Comment: If you use postgres then this will return a list of schemas and not a list of tables.

Comment: @mmitchell that is also correct for an MS SQL DB, it's retrieving a list of schemas. Is it possible to retrieve a list of tables as requested?

Comment: this is only correct answer, using query('show ...') will error with some database types like sqliite.

Answer (score 1):

Using MySQL and executing the `SHOW Tables` query with a type of `sequelize.QueryTypes.SHOWTABLES` will return an array of tables.

```
sequelize
  .query('SHOW Tables', {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SHOWTABLES
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })

// ['table1', 'table2']
```