# How to get list of talbe using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a Postgresql database using [Sequelize](https://www.google.com/search?q=sequelize%20npm&rlz=1C1SQJL_enVN856VN856&oq=sequelize%20npm&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j0l3j69i60l3.4311j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but i cannot get list of tables. Can anyone help?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217100/make-sequelize-show-tables/43217292

Answer (score 0):

In `postgreSql` query is: `select * from information_schema.tables`

use this code:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('address of database');

sequelize.query('SHOW Tables', {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SHOWTABLES
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
```

or:

```
sequelize.query('show tables').then(function(rows) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
});
```

Comment: Sorry for lately reply, I've tried your code but it showed error: ```Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: unrecognized configuration parameter "tables"```.

Comment: I just have found out solution. Just use ```sequelize.models```

Comment: @simpsons3 `sequelize.models` simply gave `{}`

Comment: @Nyxynyx on `"sequelize": "^6.6.2"`, `sequelize.models` was exactly what I needed.